# python-telegram-bot 20.1 : telegram.ext._application - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I am trying to build a nested conversation using python-telegram-bot 20.1

I am getting the following error:

2023-02-27 17:38:40,811 - telegram.ext._application - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1088, in process_update
check = handler.check_update(update)  # Should the handler handle this update?
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_conversationhandler.py", line 763, in check_update
check = candidate.check_update(update)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'check_update'

Here is the code which I am executing

```
import os
import logging

from telegram import (
    Update,
    InlineKeyboardButton,
    InlineKeyboardMarkup
)
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
    CallbackQueryHandler
)

from sddmm_constants import *

# States top Level
SELECTING_FAMILY = map(chr, range(1))

# States second level
SELECTING_ACTION = map(chr, range(1, 2))

# States third level
SHOWING_INFO, ADDING_ADDRESS, ADDING_MEMBER, EDITING_ADDRESS, EDITING_MEMBER = map(str, range(2, 7))

# States fourth level
SELECTING_MEMBER = map(str, range(7, 8))

# States meta
SUBMIT_ADDRESS_INFO, SUBMIT_MEMBER_INFO = map(str, range(8, 10))

# Stop Nested
STOPPING = map(str, range(10, 11))

# End
END = ConversationHandler.END

class Data:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", encoding='utf-8', level=logging.INFO)
        self.load_telegram_app()

    def load_telegram_app(self):
        app = Application.builder().token(os.getenv("TELE_TEST_API")).build()
        show_info_conv = ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(self.select_member, pattern=f"^{str(SHOWING_INFO)}$")],
            states={
                SELECTING_MEMBER: [CallbackQueryHandler(self.show_member_info, pattern="^sel-mem-")]
            },
            fallbacks=[
                CommandHandler("stop", self.stop)
            ],
            map_to_parent={
                END: SELECTING_ACTION,
                STOPPING: END
            }
        )
        selecting_handlers = [
            show_info_conv
        ]
        conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", self.start)],
            states={
                SELECTING_FAMILY: [CallbackQueryHandler(self.select_family, pattern="^sel-fam-")],
                SELECTING_ACTION: [selecting_handlers],
                STOPPING: [CommandHandler("start", self.start)]
            },
            fallbacks=[CommandHandler("stop", self.stop)]
        )
        app.add_handler(conv_handler)
        app.run_polling(5)

    async def start(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        user_id = update.message.from_user.id
        logging.info(f"start: [user-id] {user_id}")
        txt = "Please select family ID"
        buttons = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("100", callback_data="sel-fam-100")],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("101", callback_data="sel-fam-101")]
        ]
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
        await update.message.reply_text(text=txt, reply_markup=markup)
        return SELECTING_FAMILY
    
    async def stop(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        logging.info(f"stop: [user-id] {update.message.from_user.id}")
        await update.message.reply_text("Okay, bye.")
        return END

    async def stop_nested(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> str:
        """Completely end conversation from within nested conversation."""
        await update.message.reply_text("Okay, bye.")
        return STOPPING


    async def select_family(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        family_id = int(update.callback_query.data.replace("sel-fam-", ""))
        context.user_data["family-id"] = family_id
        logging.info(f"select_family: [user-id] {update.callback_query.from_user.id} [family-id] {family_id}")
        return await self.select_action(update, context)
    
    async def select_member(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        logging.info(f"select_member: ")
        return END

    async def select_action(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
        logging.info(f"select_action: [user-id] {update.callback_query.from_user.id} [family-id] {context.user_data['family-id']}")
        buttons = [
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Show Family Info", callback_data=str(SHOWING_INFO))]
        ]
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
        await update.callback_query.message.reply_text(text="Please select an action", reply_markup=markup)
        return SELECTING_ACTION
    
    async def show_member_info(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
        logging.info(f"show_member_info: ")
        return END

data = Data()
```

Comment: I got the answer to this issue on GitHub. Here is the link

[Answer to the question on GitHub discussion][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3566